# Regarding Events of APIs generated by hyperledger composer rest server

Tags: composer-php, blockchain, hyperledger

I am working on a POC and do not want to write any specific transaction processing functions. Created assets, participants etc. and all, so the model is ready. Generated rest api using hyperledger composer-rest-server. The frontend is developed in simple html/javascript. 
the problem is that i need events also available whenver i CRUD using composer generated APIs, but not able to figure out how.
IS it that to capture events, we need to create assets using transaction processing functions only and not via composer rest server apis -  a little novice kinda question but i am stuck in this thought.

regards,
Sophia

Answer (score 0):

I think you have figured it by now, but here's the answer for the rest of us: you can only generate events from your chaincode, and every event has to be described in your model.

Comment: Is it possible to fire some tx in the chaincode whose purpose is just to emit an event, on any newly created participant via the `rest-server`?

Comment: Yes, if the transaction is defined in the chaincode, it is possible to fire it. Unfortunately, this is the only way (as of 0.19.0) to use chaincode to query the system. You can't return a value from a transaction, so all you can do is fire an event.

One possible issue is that other clients will receive this event as well, so you don't want to put some sensitive data into it.

Comment: addParticipant is natively available - so how would I write a tx which fires for each of these actions?

Comment: If you use the CRUD operations, you won't be able to fire an event. You'll have to write a tx that adds a participant and fires an event, then lock the native "addParticipant" method so that your users only use your transaction.

That's a great feature request though.

Comment: Feature request done!  Give it a thumbs up !!! https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3840